# Swift CSVImporter framework with remote URLs

Tags: swift, csv

Initial use and testing of the framework. The examples provided and most of the searches from across the internet are using "local" or downloaded CSV files to the device, with (path:).

I would like to pass various remote URLs but there are not many examples, using (url: URL).

So far, I am simply in viewDidLoad() following the same code as provided with the sample playground file, and trying to output to the console.

I have tried to run this in a simulator for the iPhone 8 device. Running Xcode 10.1.

From the documentation, there is an ".onFail" handler, which gets invoked on the sourceURL's I have provided, but I do not know what error objects exist to do any further troubleshooting.

```
let sourceURL = URL(string: "https://files.datapress.com/leeds/dataset/leeds-city-council-dataset-register/Dataset%20register.csv")

guard let sourceURL2 = URL(string: "https://minio.l3.ckan.io/ckan/ni/resources/2477b63a-b1c4-45cc-a5ee-8e33e5b20b5b/supplies-and-services-contracts---2014.2015-yr.csv?AWSAccessKeyId=aspjTDZu90BQVi&Expires=1546982840&Signature=dLDVWMu%2Fp4RiePIRhntCX6WFMpw%3D") else {
        fatalError("URL string error")
    }

let importer = CSVImporter<[String]>(url: sourceURL)

importer?.startImportingRecords { $0 }.onFail {
            print("fail")
        }.onFinish({ importedRecords in
            print(importedRecords.count)
        })
```

Comment: you can check if the URL is a fileURL, if it is not you can download it to a temporary folder and pass that temporary file URL to the CSVImporter

Comment: @LeoDabus thanks. I had also tried `URL(fileURLWithPath: String)`as well. Is this the same fileURL that you mention? It is not clear (at least to me!) in the framework's documentation which is expected or how to handle.

Comment: if a URL returns true for isFileURL means it is a local resource otherwise it is a remote resource. URL fileURLWithPath initializer expects a local resource file path. The URL string initializer can be used for both (remote and local resources) I use it only for web links  but you need to include the URL scheme `file://` if you pass a local resource path. resuming use URL absoluteString property for string initializer and URL path property for fileURLWithPath initializer